# Powershell script to print files before moving the files to a folder

Tags: powershell

```
$source = "N:\Posting Logs"
$dest = "N:\Posting Logs\Archive" 

# Create the Archive folder if it doesn't exist

if (-not (Test-Path $dest)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $dest
}

#Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.Name} -Force
#Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse |Out-File N:\Posting Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append 
$_.FullName +$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd)  | Out-File N:\Posting Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append
```

I have commented out force move and would like to print the output of files prior to move. Added these two lines:

```
#Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse |Out-File N:\Posting Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append 
$_.FullName +$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd)  | Out-File N:\Posting Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append
```

But getting the error:

> Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt"
> does not belong to the set "unknown,string,unicode,bigendianunicode,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem"
> specified by
> the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.
> At N:\Script\movefileprint.ps1:11 char:68
> + ...  | Out-File N:\Posting Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append
> +                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Comment: Can you modify the question so we can read the code? Use the help link to see more about MarkDown format.

Comment: $source = "N:\Posting Logs"
$dest = "N:\Posting Logs\Archive" 

# Create the Archive folder if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path $dest)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $dest
}

#Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.Name} -Force
#Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse |Out-File N:\Posting Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append 
$_.FullName +$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd)  | Out-File N:\Posting Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append

Comment: #Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.Name} -Force This code moves the files to the target destination. But I would like to print before moving the files.

Comment: Tried these two lines of code but got error #Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse |Out-File N:\Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append 
$_.FullName +$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd)  | Out-File N:\ Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would like to print the output of files prior to move.

- To *preview* file moves - albeit in a manner that prints to the host (console) only - use the [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif)

  ```
  Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse | 
     Move-Item -WhatIf -Destination { Join-Path $dest $_.Name } -Force
  ```
- To *print* the paths of the files being moved *while moving them*, use the [common **`-Verbose`** parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-verbose) - albeit again in a manner that prints to the host (console) only:

  ```
  Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse | 
     Move-Item -Verbose -Destination { Join-Path $dest $_.Name } -Force
  ```
- To simply collect all *source* file paths ahead of time in a log file, before moving:

  - With a *literal* log-file path - *of necessity enclosed in quotes* if it contains *spaces* (literal paths are best enclosed in `'...'`, i.e. a [*verbatim* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)):

    ```
    Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse |
      Out-File 'N:\Posting Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt' -Append
    ```
  - With a log-file path expressed via a *variable* - quoting is then usually *optional*, but using `"..."` - i.e. an [*expandable* (interpolating) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) *explicitly* - is good habit to form:

    ```
    Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse |
      Out-File "$dest\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt" -Append
    ```
  - Note:

    - You only need the `-Append` if you truly want to append to a *preexisting* file.
    - Given that you're not using any of [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file)'s other parameters, you could simply use the `>` or `>>`, the [redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) (e.g.,
      `Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse > "$dest\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt"`).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `| Out-File N:\Posting Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt -Append`

- Because your directory path, `N:\Posting Logs\Archive`, contains *spaces* and was passed *unquoted*, `Out-File` received *two* positional arguments, `N:\Posting` and `Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt`, given that spaces act as *argument separators*.
- `Out-File` defines two *positional* parameters, `-FilePath` and `-Encoding`. Therefore the second argument - `Logs\Archive\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt` - was (inadvertently) bound to `-Encoding`, causing the error message you saw.

  - You can glean this information from the *syntax diagrams* reported by `Get-Help` and shown in the online help topics. Syntax diagrams are described in the conceptual [about_Command_Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) help topic.

Comment: @mklemento Thank you Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse > "$dest\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt" This line worked

Comment: OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt printed all the file names with date before the file can be moved

Comment: @ptolearn, thanks for accepting. It wasn't quite clear to me what  you wanted to do with the date, but if you simply want to append it to the output file: `@(Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse) + (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd) > "$dest\OutputOffAllFiles-log.txt"`